# What is a "non-noded intersection"?

Tags: postgis, nettopologysuite

Can someone provide a precise definition of what a "non-noded intersection" is? There are various GIS platforms and toolkits that have errors with this text, and Google search results for this tend to fall in the category of "drop some precision and all your problems go away" without any real explanation of what's going wrong. Given two valid geometries, why would this error occur?

References to documentation would be most helpful.

Answer (score 16):

It means that nodes cannot be in the same spatial space during intersection.  I drew you a picture.

[image]

These are the same lines, but intersected.

If you noticed, if I had dropped the node in the middle (since it is not needed) that the bottom diagram would be impossible.