# PostGIS: ST_Clip() throws non-noded intersection between LINESTRING

Tags: postgis

I have a polygon and a set of rasters. I'm trying to clip raster with polygon.
[image]
As you see, my rasters is divided into tiles. Any tiles that is contained by the polygon has ST_Overlaps(polygon, rast_geom_4326) = 'f', obviously. And it leads to non-noded intersection error.

But, I also have the same problem with this query:

```
SELECT ST_Clip(rast, ST_Transform(polygon, rast_geom_4326))
FROM landsat8
WHERE ST_Overlaps(polygon, rast_geom_4326)
```

Is there any function to dissolve the polygon with tiles, to get rid of "non-noded intersection between LINESTRING".
I've read a presentation about this error [postgis-power.pdf](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/postgis-power.pdf.7843429-0.html). But, I can't find the solution for my problem.

Comment: Perhaps you want to define the polygon in terms of an intersection (http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersection.html)?

Comment: Hi @BradHards, could you tell me more how to define the polygon. Because, I tried but it keeps throws the same error.
`SELECT ST_Intersection(polygon,rast_geom_4326) 
FROM landsat8 
WHERE ST_Intersects(polygon,rast_geom_4326)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some solutions for non-noded-problems, I still couldn't solved my problem. Then I  figured out that my polygon was invalid. I expected a rectangular, but it was a bow tie instead (ST_isValid(geom)). Therefore, the polygon was self-intersection at center.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I resolved by adding a small amount of entropy to the vectors: [How best to fix a non-noded intersection problem in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50399/how-best-to-fix-a-non-noded-intersection-problem-in-postgis)

It looks like there might be vectors which overlap, but are very close to being identical in your diagram. This may be causing the non-noded problem.

Comment: Hi @djq, I tried the solution above but it didn't solve my problem. However, I figured out my problem. My polygon was invalid. It was like a bow tie instead of a rectangular, what I expect. So it has self-intersection in the center.