# Some geometries don't work with ST_Union and gives a non-noded intersection

Tags: postgis

I'm getting a lot of errors like this:

```
GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (147.254 -42.8705, 147.254 -42.8705) and LINESTRING (147.254 -42.8705, 147.254 -42.8705) at 147.25355728849621 -42.870521684000678
```

I am calling `ST_MakeValid(ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(mpoly)))` on an aggregate of all rows that match my filter.

Comment: You want to call ST_MakeValid before ST_Union. If union runs into an invalid geometry, it's more likely to throw a topo exception

Comment: Turns out this isn't enough.

Comment: yeah I ran MakeValid before Union and I still got this error

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question at [How best to fix a non-noded intersection problem in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50399/how-best-to-fix-a-non-noded-intersection-problem-in-postgis).  Some have had success by performing [ST_MakeValid](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_MakeValid.html), [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) or [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html)  to the geometry *before* to performing the union. I see you tried `SnapToGrid`. Have you tried something like:

```
ST_Union(ST_MakeValid(mpoly))
```

or

```
ST_Union(ST_Buffer(mpoly, 1e-5))
```

The presentation  [PostGIS: Tips for Power Users](http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations/3369.pdf) outlines some potential sources of trouble when unioning geometries.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of functions,
add the grid size to snap 0.0001 for degrees,
collenct only polygons for query ( 3 stands for polygons):

```
Select
ST_Union(
  ST_CollectionExtract(
    ST_MakeValid(
      ST_SnapToGrid(geom,0.0001)
    ),3
  )
)
From
  mpoly
```