# How to check if blocks touch by walls and continuous?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a number of blocks that are lying next to each other in all directions.

[image]

So, the user can select individual and multiple blocks.
There is a "must" requirement to select multiple blocks:

block have to touch each other by their walls, like this:

[image]

this is ok, but these are not okay,
[image]
[image]

because some blocks touch only by edges.
So, I have been using the `st_numgeometries(st_union(geom))` and when it return 1 it is okay, otherwise not. However, for the selection (the user selected all blocks)
[image]

I am getting multi polygon which contains two polygons,

[image]

How should look like my query to get 1 (so they should be ok with this kind of selection)?

Comment: This sounds to me like you rather want to implement an on-click check based on row & column cell indices on the frontend - that way you could easily provide live info on, and check overall, validity *before* issuing any queries.

Comment: @geozelot how can I implement that? using openlayers?

Comment: looks like a rounding issue - try snapping to a fixed precision grid

Comment: Well, the actual logic would be plain JavaScript - two objects, one holding valid cell ids, one holding invalid cell ids and for each feature selection, check both maps for adjacent cells (by row_index +- 1 or column_index +- 1), then update the maps if needed (valid to invalid or vice versa).

Comment: seems to be too complex

Comment: @IanTurton can you give more details, pls?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165421/some-geometries-dont-work-with-st-union-and-gives-a-non-noded-intersection