# PostGIS: ST_Union fails with valid polygons?

Tags: postgis, dissolve, union

I am working with [this dataset](https://gapanalysis.usgs.gov/padus/data/download/). I have imported it into a Postgres 9.6 database with shp2pgsql as follows:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 5070:5070 us_govt/PADUS1_4Fee.shp usgovt | psql -d mydb
```

I have made all the polygons valid:

```
UPDATE usgovt
 SET geom=ST_Multi(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_MakeValid(geom), 3))
 WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(geom);
```

Then simplified them, and re-validated them:

```
UPDATE usgovt SET geom_simpler=ST_Multi(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(geom,0.5));
```

To confirm, all the simplified polygons are valid (the following produces zero):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usgovt WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(geom_simpler);
```

However, trying an `ST_Union` on a group of the polygons fails:

```
# SELECT ST_Union(geom_simpler) AS geom from usgovt WHERE gap_sts='2';
ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (-3.36702e+06 4.94515e+06, -3.36699e+06 4.94512e+06) and LINESTRING (-3.36699e+06 4.94512e+06, -3.36702e+06 4.94515e+06) at -3367018.7763304636 4945150.2479274161
```

Why could this be failing, and how can I debug it?

**UPDATE**: Tried buffering with `SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom_simpler, 0.000001)) AS geom from usgovt WHERE gap_sts='2';`, but that fails with: `ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 3216270.6962009948 -12370.16660008162 at 3216270.6962009948 -12370.16660008162`.

**UPDATE 2**: I've tried creating my own version of `ST_Union` with better exception handling, as suggested in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90284/7785) to a related question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION safe_union(geom_a geometry, geom_b geometry)
RETURNS geometry AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN ST_Union(geom_a, geom_b);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            BEGIN
                RETURN ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom_a, 0.00001), ST_Buffer(geom_b, 0.00001));
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN OTHERS THEN
                        RETURN ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON EMPTY');
    END;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' STABLE STRICT;
```

It returns `CREATE FUNCTION` but when I actually try to use it:

```
SELECT safe_union(geom_simpler) AS geom from usgovt WHERE gap_sts='2';
```

I get `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`.

Also, I'm not sure how safe this method will be, if it's unioning tens of thousands of polygons, because I don't understand the internals of how `ST_Union` works.

Is it possible that it could successfully union 5000 polygons, then get to the 5001st, hit an error, and silently replace the union of the previous 5000 with a null polygon, ultimately producing an extremely inaccurate result?

Comment: because you have a non-noded intersection between two line strings.

Comment: Should it be possible for `ST_Union` to fail with valid input? Should I report this as a PostGIS bug?

Comment: There's a difference between a valid line string and a valid input set for union.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50399/how-best-to-fix-a-non-noded-intersection-problem-in-postgis

Comment: @Richard: yes, it's possible to fail with valid input.  The "non-noded intersection" refers to an error encountered during the union operations, not any condition in your data.

Comment: Just tried `SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(geom_simpler, 0.00001)) AS geom from usgovt WHERE gap_sts='2'`: also failed with `non-noded intersection` error. Any ideas (can't parse linked question), or is PostGIS just fundamentally broken in this respect?

Comment: @iant Thanks for posting the link. I'm struggling to understand the recommended solution - please could you elaborate a bit? Do I need to write my own version of `ST_Union` with exception handling?

Comment: Also having this issue. Huge polygon table, used ST_MAKEVALID to fix a number of self intersecting errors, then ran ST_ISVALID to see that there were no longer any errors. Then I ran ST_UNION and after a while it said that 'TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING....'

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with valid geometries, the solution for me was to run :

```
SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 0.00001))
```

So in your case :

```
SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(geom_simpler, 0.00001)) AS geom from usgovt WHERE gap_sts='2';
```

If it also failed, something else is wrong in topology.