# Snap to grid with sf in R

Tags: r, snapping, sf

Is there a snap to grid function available in `sf` for R similar to `ST_SnapToGrid(geometry geomA, float size)`in PostGIS? It is mentioned as a solution to [non-noded intersection problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50399/how-best-to-fix-a-non-noded-intersection-problem-in-postgis) for PostGIS and am looking for a solution in R. Using other snap options with just the polygon lead to geometry errors (even with small tolerance).

Comment: Perhaps all coordinates can be rounded to certain precision, for the same effect as ST_SnapToGrid

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. I ran into errors when I tried to simplify my features as bits of some polygons were missing bits of other polygons or `st_snap`.

Comment: I've posted example below

Answer (score 2):

Rounding coordinates may be equivalent to snapping all of the shapes coordinates to a regular grid.

Before -

```
> pnt = st_point(c(0,0))
> pol = st_buffer(pnt, 1)
> plot(pol)
```

[image]

After -

```
> pol[[1]] = round(pol[[1]], 1)
> plot(pol)
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try this later and mark it as accepted once I've checked that it works, but it looks promising!

Answer (score 2):

The R equivalent of the `ST_SnapToGrid` in PostGIS is in the `lwgeom` package:

```
# Snap to grid of 5000 m
lwgeom::st_snap_to_grid(x, 5000)
```

Works well to solve the non-noded intersection problem, and is quicker than applying a buffer of the same tolerance.